# Does QueryList monitor innerHTML changes of the elements?

Tags: angular

I was wondering what kind of changes does QueryList track? For example, the following code does not `console.log` on changes. Does it mean that `changes` will be triggered only if  `ElementRef` has been added/removed? Thanks (and sorry for fairly basic question).

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div>
      <div #header>header</div>
      <div #cell>{{name}}</div> 
    </div>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('cell', { read: ElementRef}) cells: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit () {
    setTimeout(() => this.name = 'cell2', 5000);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.cells.changes.subscribe(() => console.log('component changes'));
  }
}
```

Comment: `QueryList` is just like a type of variable and it does nothing by default. your `ViewChild` controls the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this article](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e) by Netanel Basal, the `QueryList.changes` observable emits a value when elements are added to, removed from, or moved in the list:

> **QueryList**
>
> changes() — Changes can be observed by subscribing to the *changes*
>   Observable. Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the
>   query list will be updated, and the changes observable of the query
>   list will emit a new value.

Modifying properties of an element of the list should not trigger the `QueryList.changes` observable, as you already noticed.